Underdetermined system of equations in photon absorption in indirect semiconductors
Consider the photon absorption in indirect semiconductors. The relevant equations are
$$\textbf{Energy conservation:}\quad E_{photon} = E_g - E_{phonon}(q)$$
and
$$\textbf{Momentum conservation:}\quad k_{photon} = k_e - q$$
Suppose we know the dispersion relation $E_{phonon}(q)$ and $E_{photon}$ is related to $k_{photon}$ as $E_{photon} = \hbar k_{photon} c$ and $E_{photon}$ is not known and should come out from these equations(?). (I am not sure about this)
This means we have at least 3 unknowns $k_{photon}, k_e, q$. While the number of equations is only 2. So the system seems underdetermined. How to solve this conundrum?
